# How to read file and calculate graph properties in igraph python

Tags: python, igraph, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to the igraph python and I have read the tutorial but I cannot understand very well. 
I need some help to calculate the graph properties of my data. My data is in bpseq format and I do not know how to read the file in igraph. 
The graph properties that I need to get is

1. Articulation point
2. Average path length
3. Average node betweenness
4. Variance of node betweenness
5. Average edge betweenness
6. Variance of edge betweenness
7. Average co-citation coupling
8. Average bibliographic coupling
9. Average closeness centrality
10. Diameter
11. Graph Density

This is the example of my dataset. The # is the name of the RNA class, the first column is the position, the alphabet is the base and the third column is the pointer. Suppose the base should be the node. and the bond between the nucleotide base should be the edge. But I do not know how to do it. There are about 2,00 dataset that looks like below but that is the one of the RNA class.

```
# RF00001_AF095839_1_346-228 5S_rRNA
1 G 118
2 C 117
3 G 116
4 U 115
5 A 114
6 C 113
7 G 112
8 G 111
9 C 110
10 C 0
11 A 0
12 U 0
13 A 0
14 C 0
15 U 0
16 A 0
17 U 0
18 G 0
19 G 36
20 G 35
21 G 34
22 A 33
23 A 0
24 U 0
25 A 0
26 C 0
27 A 0
28 C 0
29 C 0
30 U 0
31 G 0
32 A 0
33 U 22
34 C 21
35 C 20
36 C 19
37 G 0
38 U 106
39 C 105
40 C 104
41 G 103
42 A 0
43 U 0
44 U 0
45 U 0
46 C 0
47 A 0
48 G 0
49 A 0
50 A 0
51 G 0
52 U 0
53 U 0
54 A 0
55 A 0
56 G 67
57 C 66
58 C 65
59 U 64
60 C 0
61 A 0
62 U 0
63 C 0
64 A 59
65 G 58
66 G 57
67 C 56
68 A 0
69 U 0
70 C 0
71 C 0
72 U 0
73 A 0
74 A 0
75 G 0
76 U 0
77 A 0
78 C 0
79 U 0
80 A 0
81 G 96
82 G 95
83 G 94
84 U 93
85 G 92
86 G 91
87 G 0
88 C 0
89 G 0
90 A 0
91 C 86
92 C 85
93 A 84
94 C 83
95 C 82
96 U 81
97 G 0
98 G 0
99 G 0
100 A 0
101 A 0
102 C 0
103 C 41
104 G 40
105 G 39
106 A 38
107 U 0
108 G 0
109 U 0
110 G 9
111 C 8
112 U 7
113 G 6
114 U 5
115 A 4
116 C 3
117 G 2
118 C 1
119 U 0
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I really hope someone can help me and guide me on using igraph python.

Comment: It would be great if you could link to the specific file formatting you are using. Quickly googling for a standard returned multiple different results. Ideally, you can even upload an excerpt of your own data and describe it. Also, the question in its current state is way too broad. What have you already tried? For many of the points, there exist functions that you can find in the [online docs](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-module.html), even though I admit that it is terribly structured.

Comment: @dennlinger I already my question by inlcude the example of my data . I do not know how to plot the graph based on my data and I do not know how to get the graph properties. I've read the manual tutorial but I cannot understand. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please replace the picture with a proper code format (simply indent by four spaces to start a code block). Also, is this graph directed, and should the metrics be computed as such? And are the edge arguments relevant (i.e. the bases A/G/U/C)? I feel this is likely going to get moved to discussion soon, if you're still interested in solving this.

Comment: @dennlinger Is there any chance that I could have your email address for me to discuss with you personally about this problem ? I would appreciate it if you could help me solving this. Actually, I am doing the experiment just like this research is done. Here is the link to the research https://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2164-15-127

Comment: @dennlinger I have emailed you, you can check it.